# spring security will not exclude service and dao layers

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am having a big trouble with spring security which caused me an entire week to find out where there issue was.

I checked stackoverflow as well as blogs and spring docs as well but i could not come to the conclusion. The problem is I have my layers service and dao which all work before the security implementation but surprisingly spring security blocks and will not exclude my interfaces! The other thing is that within the security package where I keep my custom spring classes there is a business class which can handle requests works like a charm but when i attempt to use my interfaces it will not work! I cannot create an instance of an interface sadly. The below I am adding my code and stack trace.

**My project Structure is***

```
com.xxx.dao => where my dao interfaces reside

com.xxx.service => where my service interfaces reside

com.xxx.security => where my custom spring security extended classes reside, also there is a class which does business logic in the case my service and dao interface were supposed to do
```

**I am using**

ZK 6.5.2

Spring Framework and Security 3.1.2

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <description><![CDATA[My ZK Application]]></description>
    <display-name>CMC_REPORTING</display-name>

    <!-- Spring Security Configuration -->
    <filter><!-- the filter-name must be preserved, do not change it! -->
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Spring configuration -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml 
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
    </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Initialize spring context -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Enable webapp Scopes -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- log4j config -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- ZK -->
    <listener>
        <description>ZK listener for session cleanup</description>
        <listener-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.HttpSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <description>ZK loader for ZUML pages</description>
        <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet</servlet-class>

        <!-- Must. Specifies URI of the update engine (DHtmlUpdateServlet). It 
            must be the same as <url-pattern> for the update engine. -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>update-uri</param-name>
            <param-value>/zkau</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <!-- Optional. Specifies whether to compress the output of the ZK loader. 
            It speeds up the transmission over slow Internet. However, if you configure 
            a filter to post-processing the output, you might have to disable it. Default: 
            true <init-param> <param-name>compress</param-name> <param-value>true</param-value> 
            </init-param> -->
        <!-- [Optional] Specifies the default log level: OFF, ERROR, WARNING, INFO, 
            DEBUG and FINER. If not specified, the system default is used. <init-param> 
            <param-name>log-level</param-name> <param-value>OFF</param-value> </init-param> -->
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup><!-- Must -->
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.zul</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.zhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- [Optional] Uncomment it if you want to use richlets. <servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name> <url-pattern>/zk/*</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping> -->
    <servlet>
        <description>The asynchronous update engine for ZK</description>
        <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet</servlet-class>

        <!-- [Optional] Specifies whether to compress the output of the ZK loader. 
            It speeds up the transmission over slow Internet. However, if your server 
            will do the compression, you might have to disable it. Default: true <init-param> 
            <param-name>compress</param-name> <param-value>true</param-value> </init-param> -->
        <!-- [Optional] Specifies the AU extension for particular prefix. <init-param> 
            <param-name>extension0</param-name> <param-value>/upload=com.my.MyUploader</param-value> 
            </init-param> -->
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/zkau/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- [Optional] Uncomment if you want to use the ZK filter to post process 
        the HTML output generated by other technology, such as JSP and velocity. 
        <filter> <filter-name>zkFilter</filter-name> <filter-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutFilter</filter-class> 
        <init-param> <param-name>extension</param-name> <param-value>html</param-value> 
        </init-param> <init-param> <param-name>compress</param-name> <param-value>true</param-value> 
        </init-param> </filter> <filter-mapping> <filter-name>zkFilter</filter-name> 
        <url-pattern>your URI pattern</url-pattern> </filter-mapping> -->

    <!-- DSP (optional) Uncomment it if you want to use DSP However, it is turned 
        on since zksandbox uses DSP to generate CSS. <servlet> <servlet-name>dspLoader</servlet-name> 
        <servlet-class>org.zkoss.web.servlet.dsp.InterpreterServlet</servlet-class> 
        <init-param> <param-name>class-resource</param-name> <param-value>true</param-value> 
        </init-param> </servlet> <servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>dspLoader</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>*.dsp</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping> -->

    <!-- [Optional] Session timeout -->
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <!-- [Optional] MIME mapping -->
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>doc</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-word</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>gif</extension>
        <mime-type>image/gif</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>htm</extension>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>html</extension>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>jpeg</extension>
        <mime-type>image/jpeg</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>jpg</extension>
        <mime-type>image/jpeg</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>js</extension>
        <mime-type>text/javascript</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>pdf</extension>
        <mime-type>application/pdf</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>png</extension>
        <mime-type>image/png</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>txt</extension>
        <mime-type>text/plain</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xls</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-excel</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xml</extension>
        <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>zhtml</extension>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>zul</extension>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.zul</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.zhtml</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Moved the component scan to applicationContext.xml -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />

    <!-- Bean definitions -->
    <bean id="businessObjectsDAO" class="com.xxx.dao.BusinessObjectsDAOImpl" />
    <bean id="businessObjectsService" class="com.xxx.service.BusinessObjectsServiceImpl" />
    <bean id="databaseDAO" class="com.xxx.dao.DatabaseDAOImpl" />
    <bean id="databaseService" class="com.xxx.service.DatabaseServiceImpl" />
    <bean id="officeSuiteDAO" class="com.xxx.dao.OfficeSuiteDAOImpl" />
    <bean id="officeSuiteService" class="com.xxx.service.OfficeSuiteServiceImpl" />

</beans>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

 <!-- I have defined all packages -->
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.controller, com.xxx.dao, com.xxx.domain, com.xxx.security, com.xxx.service" />
</beans>
```

**applicationContext-security.xml**

```
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <!-- Enabling annotation use in classes -->
    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

    <http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <!-- ZK au has to be accessed anonymously -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/zkau/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"
            requires-channel="any" />

        <!-- allowing access to css resources -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"
            requires-channel="any" />

        <!-- allowing access to images resources -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"
            requires-channel="any" />

        <!-- allowing access to layout resources -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/layout/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"
            requires-channel="any" />

        <!-- allowing access to login page -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/login.zul" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

        <!-- After defining other resources secure all pages and links -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

        <!-- Custom Login Filter -->
        <custom-filter ref="customAuthenticationFilter"
            position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />

        <!-- Custom Logout Filter -->
        <custom-filter ref="customLogoutFilter" position="LOGOUT_FILTER" />
    </http>

    <!-- Custom Authentication Filter -->
    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationFilter"
        class="com.xxx.security.CustomAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler"
            ref="failureHandler" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler"
            ref="successHandler" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Custom Authentication Filter -->
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <!-- Custom Authentication Provider For details check the regarding class -->
    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider"
        class="com.xxx.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider" />

    <!-- Successful login handler -->
    <beans:bean id="successHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/index.zul" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Failure login handler -->
    <beans:bean id="failureHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login.zul?login_error=1" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Custom Logout Handler -->
    <beans:bean id="customLogoutHandler" class="com.xxx.security.CustomLogoutHandler" />
    <beans:bean id="customLogoutFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="/login.zul" />
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="customLogoutHandler" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_logout" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Access Denied Handler -->
    <beans:bean id="accessDeniedHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl">
        <beans:property name="errorPage" value="/accessDenied.zul" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Customized Login Entry Point -->
    <beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" scope="prototype"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.zul" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans> 

*** This is the trick***
```

**BusinessObjects DAO**

```
@Secured(value = { "IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" })
public interface BusinessObjectsDAO {

//business code

}
```

**BusinessObjects Service**

```
 @Service(value = "businessObjectsService")
   public class BusinessObjectsServiceImpl implements BusinessObjectsService {

   //business code

   }
```

**BusinessObjects DAO**
     @Repository(value = "businessObjectsDAO")
        public class BusinessObjectsDAOImpl implements BusinessObjectsDAO {
        //business code
        }

**Stack Trace ***

```
org.zkoss.zel.ELException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.zkoss.zel.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:614)
    org.zkoss.zel.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:161)
    org.zkoss.xel.zel.XelELResolver.invoke(XelELResolver.java:148)
    org.zkoss.zel.impl.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:166)
    org.zkoss.zel.impl.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    org.zkoss.xel.zel.ELXelExpression.evaluate(ELXelExpression.java:40)
    org.zkoss.zk.xel.impl.SimpleEvaluator.evaluate(SimpleEvaluator.java:72)
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.AbstractEvalRef.evaluate(AbstractEvalRef.java:48)
    org.zkoss.zk.xel.ExValue.getValue(ExValue.java:109)
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.Property.getValue(Property.java:134)
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.Property.assign0(Property.java:227)
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.Property.assign(Property.java:169)
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.ComponentInfo.applyProperties(ComponentInfo.java:729)
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.AbstractUiFactory.newComponent(AbstractUiFactory.java:106)
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:809)
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:778)
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:687)
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:651)
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:824)
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:778)
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:687)
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:651)
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.doGet(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:136)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly is the problem - the security config looks like it is just restricting all urls (other than resources/login/etc) which will block access to the controllers - what do you mean by "but surprisingly spring security blocks and will not exclude my interfaces"

Comment: Also, what is happening in the BulkAuthController on line 22 where you get the NPE in the stacktrace?

Comment: @rhinds i mean interfaces my classes which handle requests and carry out tasks. Bulkauth controller has a lists collects data from my dao interface which is connected to a data source. 5 minutes ago i set auto-config as true all worked like a charm but I restarted the server and had the failures back again because i have customized security

Comment: I have finally ended up finding the solution I altered the code and commented what changes I have made